# Unordered Map Performing Much Slower than Map

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashmap

Say I am attempting to solve the [two-sum problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/). Below are two samples of the same algorithm, one using an ordered map, and one using an un-ordered map.

Using unordered_map:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        unordered_map<int, int> d;
        int indx {0};
        for(auto num: nums){
            int complement {target - num};
            if(d.find(complement) != d.end()) {
                vector<int> answer {d[complement], indx};
                return answer;
            } else {
                d[num] = indx;
                indx++;
            }
        }
    return vector<int> {-1, -1};
    }
};
```

Using (ordered) map (the only change):

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        map<int, int> d;
        int indx {0};
        for(auto num: nums){
            int complement {target - num};
            if(d.find(complement) != d.end()) {
                vector<int> answer {d[complement], indx};
                return answer;
            } else {
                d[num] = indx;
                indx++;
            }
        }
    return vector<int> {-1, -1};
    }
};
```

With my understanding of the differences between the two objects, I do not understand why unordered_map is performing more slowly than the ordered map by a factor of three.

Comment: FWIW `std::unordered_map` is not a great implementation of a hash map in terms of performance.  The requirements placed on the container means that under the hood it is basically a `std::vector<std::list<T>>`.  Sure you'll O(1) complexity but every access is going to cause at least on cache miss and most likely more.

Comment: Ah, gotcha'. I was thinking complexity = speed, but this makes sense.

Comment: Recommendation: Turn these into runnable examples complete with an input set that demonstrates the issue. This will allow people to run profiles rather than guess at the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unordered_map has to allocate and copy to grow over and over while the map just allocates nodes.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: Try reserving space

Comment: Setting the size to `nums.size()` should avoid resizing. Half that probably works too since keys are put into buckets and you are like to find a match before the end as well.